# Field with null=True and blank=True serializer None error in JS

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a model

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
    question_image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to='question')
    option = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False),size=4)
    answer = models.IntegerField(choices=((1,'1'),(2,'2'),(3,'3'),(4,'4')))
    description = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True )
```

coressponding serializer is

```
class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('id', 'question', 'question_image', 'option', 'answer', 'description')
    read_only_fields = ('id',)
```

The serialized object I get is

> {'description': None, 'id': 1, 'answer': 3, 'question_image': None, 'option': ['27', '28', '29', '31'], 'question': 'How many states are there in India?'}

I want to use this JSON in javascript which gives me error `None` is not defined. What is the simplest and clean solution to change None to null in serializer?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you received a list of objects and stored in a variable named `json`.

You can pass empty string to the variable if description return `None`.

```
  $.each(json, function(key,value){

    if ( value.description ) {
      var description = value.description;
    } else {
      var description = "";
    };

  });
```